# Turn a computer to a BLE transmitter?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

Having a computer with the bluetooth 4.0 supported (Lenovo thinkpad T450). I don't know if I can turn my computer to a Bluetooth Low Energy transmitter as a beacon Tag.

Comment: If you have Windows 10 this may be possible.  Before Windows 10 it is not.

Comment: @davidyoung: Thank for your answer. I'm using linux. I have tried to search on Internet but there is no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BlueZ to send a beacon transmission.  An example that transmits the AltBeacon format can be found here:

https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/altbeacon-reference/blob/master/altbeacon_transmit

Similar commands can be used to send other beacon formats as well.